# Boolean Logical not operator on Integer Java

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic, logical-operators

Is there a method that takes in 16-bit unsigned integer, and performs a boolean logical NOT operation on it.

Comment: 9 is "boolean logical not" 6? Is it because a 6 is a 9 upside down?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Boolean operators are for boolean arguments. Did you mean *bit not* operator? Also can you explain why `not(6)` should be evaluated to `9`?

Comment: Sorry, I might have used the wrong terminology.
6 in binary is 0110. the not operation on all bits is 1001. Which is 9 in decimal

Comment: @JohnDoe Integers are on 32 bits and signed.

Comment: well, that really depends on how many bits you use to represent the integer. 6 as an int is actually 00000000..000110.

Comment: 6 is actually `00000000000000000000000000000110`, so flipping the bits is not going to give 9.

Comment: I will rephrase the question. Is there an existing method for unsigned integers?

Comment: If you want it to come out to 9, I think this would work: (~i&0xF)

Comment: I understand now that 9 would not be the answer, I have rephrased the question. I am sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bitwise negation-operator is `~`. Example:

```
int i = 6;
System.out.println(~i);  // Prints -7
```

If you want to treat the integer as an unsigned 16-bit integer (i.e. disregard from the most significant 16 bits) you should do

```
public static int u16neg(int i) {
    return ~i & 0xFFFF;
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(u16neg(0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000110)); // 65529
System.out.println(       0b00000000_00000000_11111111_11111001);  // 65529
```

Comment: Dagnabbit... It's always a race to get the answer out.